# Testing a method in a class which calls an overridden method

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

Suppose I have the following classes:

```py
class A():
    def method1(self, x):
       x = x * 2
       x = self.method2(x)
       return x

    def method2(self, x):
       raise NotImplementedError
```

```py
class B(A):
    def method2(self, x):
        return x + 5
```

If I am writing unit tests for class A, 
(a little new to unittesting)

1. **How do I test `method1`?**
   Since it calls a method which is overridden in a subclass.
2. **Do I create an object of class `A` or class `B`?** (I am testing `A`)
   Creating an object for A would result in a `NotImplementedError`. A possible solution would be to use an object of `B` to test this method, or possibly, testing this method when writing tests for class `B`.

**Edit**:
Though I am not completely fixed on the design, class `A` will most probably not be directly instantiated.

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? What do you expect to happen / not happen when you call the method? Do you see `A` as an abstract class? Do you expect the production code to instantiate `A` directly (without using a subclass)?

Comment: Sorry for being a little vague. I have not decided on that part yet, but most probably, `A` will not be instantiated.

Comment: @Goyo, how would that change the answer provided by @Mureinik?

Comment: I did not pay much attention to the answer since I don't think the question can be properly answered without knowing what you want to test. If the production code is not going to instantiate `A` then maybe your test shouldn't do it either, but you might have reasons to do it. The answer may or may not help you to test whatever you want to test, I don't know. You are in a better position to judge that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on an instance of `B` - you'd probably want to unit test `B` too, but if you're testing `A`, you shouldn't rely on other class' logic.

You could test that calling `method1` raises a `NotImplementedError`, but that's fragile - the test would also pass if `method1` raised that error directly, regardless of `method2`.

A better approach could be to create a dummy class that overrides `method2` and just returns `x` as-is, and use it for testing `A`.